# tilemaps in 2d games

Tags: java, graphics, 2d

I have 160 'world tiles', each world tile has 25 region tiles, each region tile is 100x100 grid 50px by 50px

what do i need to know to be able to make it such that:

1). Initial zoom is the region tile. (100x100)
2). When player 'explores' onto another region tile, the 2nd region tile is added to the player view; and the player is now able to zoom in and out to show all explored.. down to initial region.

do I just create one large image and work with that?? I am confused and been looking through a few java game programming books to find an answer on how to approach this with no avail.

Comment: This depends.  Do you want to allow for a variable zoom or stepped zoom.  Ie, you can see a single region, step out to see two regions, step out to see three...etc...

Comment: @DiegoCNascimento Too much coding to do...

Comment: I would like variable zoom. I don't want it fixed such that when the explore that is now the set zoom. I would like it so you can zoom in and out-- with the MAXIMUM zoom ofcourse being the 100x100 initial region

Comment: Use a modelview matrix to apply the zoom. Cull the unseen tiles.

Comment: Is there a good book you can recommend to learn how to work with that?

Comment: the 3D math chapters of Game Engine Architecture by Jason Gregory might expand your mind.